# Navigation controller inside tab bar controller (like WhatsApp or FB Messenger)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm making an iOS tab-based app, and what I'm trying to implement is hiding tab bar when navigate to further screen. But I'd like to do like Whats App or Facebook Messenger, like this demo:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X90LH.jpg

Expected: When navigate to sub screen using navigation controller, the tab bar is hide, but when navigate back to home screen, the tab bar is already there and ready to show.

I tried `tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true` or `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true`, but it doesn't give me the expected behaviours

Can anyone explain me this,

Thank you

Comment: create a custom tab bar (with custom UIView and implement all basic features of tab bar on your own) add it as subview to your parent view and when you push another view controller and enable `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` you should get expected behaviour

Comment: What is your first viewController .. ?? i mean when app loads which VC you shows??

Comment: @SaifanNadaf, my first viewcontroller is Tabbar controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you require, you need a Tab Bar Controller inside your Navigation Controller, not the other way round.

Considering that your Tab bar controller is your **home screen**. You need to have a Navigation controller with this tab bar controller as it's root view controller.

Then from the tab bar controller when you navigate to a sub-screen, this action should push the controller representing your sub-screen on the navigation controller. That's it.

See the storyboard snapshot for the setup I described.

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: is this working.. ?? i guess we can't embed TabBarVC in NavigationController

Comment: It's working fine.
With the tab bar controller present, add a navigation controller in the storyboard. Delete the default root view controller that comes with it. Then ctrl-drag from navigation controller to the tab bar controller and select it as the root view controller.

Comment: It's working, thank you, exactly what I mean. My previous approach was put NavigationController behind the tab bar controller, that's the reason why. :-D

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: I have tried to embed a **TabBarController** in a **NavigationController** and Xcode doesn't allow to do that. The best approach is just to enable the **Hide Bottom Bar on Push** or by code **hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true** in the last view controller that you want to show. It produces the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an example that will be useful to you...In scene delegate I set the root navigationController like this:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
}
```

add my extension (if you don't want to use it, configure navBar as you prefer) to configure navigation Bar with large Titles:

```
extension UIViewController {
func configureNavigationBar(largeTitleColor: UIColor, backgoundColor: UIColor, tintColor: UIColor, title: String, preferredLargeTitle: Bool) {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: largeTitleColor]
        navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: largeTitleColor]
        navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = backgoundColor

        navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
        navigationController?.navigationBar.compactAppearance = navBarAppearance
        navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance

        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = preferredLargeTitle
        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = tintColor
        navigationItem.title = title

    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = backgoundColor
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = tintColor
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        navigationItem.title = title
    }
}
}
```

Now set your viewController, under the controller class declare your tabBarController:

```
let tabBar = UITabBarController()
```

in viewDidLoad call the extension to configure navigation bar and set the right button to call the pushViewControllerAction:

```
configureNavigationBar(largeTitleColor: .white, backgoundColor: .red, tintColor: .white, title: "Prova", preferredLargeTitle: true)
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Go", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleSecondController))
```

now set the tabBar (i don't add an item to do it faster) with controller to display in it:

```
tabBar.tabBar.barStyle = .default
    let controller1 = Prova1ViewController() // my controller displayed have a gray BG
    tabBar.viewControllers = [controller1]
    view.addSubview(tabBar.view)
```

after viewDidLoad set the function to call your controller with a push action:

```
@objc func handleSecondController() {
    let controller = secondController() // my controller called have a purple BG
    navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}
```

[image]

Hope the help :)

Comment: This is also a working answer for me along with the answer above your answer. Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

Edit: After reviewing my code, I manage to make it work with a simple solution by using `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true`, set this to detail view then I got what I want.

Don't know why I tried this at the first time but it doesn't work, maybe I was wrong somewhere :)